# What should our chatroom name be?

Tags: discussion

After seeing a similar discussion in the Language learning beta site I want to raise this discussion here. Other SE sites have creative, cool room names that not only is related to the site but is awsome. And our chatroom looks basic and plain. I mean look at the other sites:

- "Root Access" for Super User
- "The DMZ" for Security
- "The Renderfarm" for Blender
- "The Litter Box" for Pets
- "The Hangar" for Aviation
- "You Are Here" for Travel

So, what should our chatroom be renamed to? And **only one entry per answer.**

Answer (score 4):

### Chat Hub

---

I suggest this name as windows mobile and hubs have a long history starting from the Games hub, People hub, Insider hub etc... and finally the Feedback hub.

Answer (score 2):

### Chat Corner

---

To match the built-in features Kid's Corner and Apps Corner.

Comment: I haven't know anyone who actually used that features. Maybe my friends are too young and trust others too much.